# Flipping Right-Side and Left-Side Animation of a Humanoid Character

Tags: animation, armature

I have an animation that I want to flip with respect to the spine i.e. the right limbs should take the animation of the left limbs and the left limbs acquire the animation of the right limbs (as shown below).

How would I go about doing that?

[image]

Comment: if you want to flip the pose you need to make sure that the bone are correctly named, i.e. leg_R and leg_L, or leg.R and leg.L (then names need the R and L suffixes), then you press Ctrl C and Ctrl Shift V

Comment: Thanks @moonboots. That did not work for me. The animation comes from Mixamo, and inside the armature, bones are named "mixamorig:<componentName>", so I added L and R to the limbs e.g. "mixamorig:LeftArm" becomes "mixamorig:LeftArm:L", and "mixamorig:RightHandMiddle4" becomes "mixamorig:RightHandMiddle4:R". I ended up having only one limb moving in the copied/pasted animation, and it was neither doing its original animation nor its expected flipped animation.

Comment: the bones need to have the same name, so for example leg.R and leg.L, not rightleg.R and leftleg.L

Comment: Also use periods ('.') not colons (':') before the 'L' and 'R'.

Comment: It works now thanks :-) On the downside, the renaming of the bones seems to have messed up something internal. When I export the new animation to FBX to use in Unity, the model does not get animated like usual.